# Derivation of $dV = A \, dx$ for finding volume of solids with cross sections

Tags: calculus, integration

How come $dv = \text{Area} \cdot dx$? Isn't the area multiplied by $dx$ the volume of one solid?

And also, what is the integral of the surface area?

Comment: If you consider that $dV$ is an infinitely small slice of volume, then since $dx$ is an infinitely small length, you find that a cross-sectional area multiplied by $dx$ should give you $dV.$ For your second question, a general way to do that is by using vector calculus.

Comment: @Allawonder That makes more sense. But how come the definite integral of a small slice of volume gives you the total volume?

Comment: Because to integrate is to combine all those infinitesimal slices together.

Comment: Surface integral is the integral of surface area. How might you get the formula for computing it? The idea is behind two formulas: $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = |a| |b| \sin \varphi$ and $dS \cdot \cos \alpha = dA$. The first is cross product and the other is that we projected the surface onto a plane. Recall that $F_x = F \cos \beta$. So, the only problem is to find the cosine of $\alpha$. Hint: Consider the tangent plane equation. Conclude from it the normal vector expression (how do you know the normal vector from the equation of a plane?!). Compute the cosine. Integrate and you are done.

Comment: Note: By Divergence theorem, you can compute the surface integral of the first kind through the volume integral: $$\iiint_\Omega \operatorname{div} \vec{F} dV = \iint_{\partial \Omega} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} dS $$ where $\vec{n} $ is the unit normal vector of the surface $\partial \Omega$. The theorem itself means the generalisation of the fundamental theorem of calculus (leading to Stokes-Cartana theorem) . The volume may be expressed as $dV = dxdydz = dxdA$.